# In a GraphQL/Relay mutation that creates a model, is there a way to get back the model ID?

Tags: relayjs

We're using Relay and GraphQL in a new project.

We've got a Relay mutation that creates a new model in the DB:

```
export default class AddCampaignMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
    getMutation() {
        return Relay.QL`mutation { addCampaign }`;
    }
    getVariables() {
        return {
            type: this.props.campaignType
        };
    }
    getFatQuery() {
        return Relay.QL`
            fragment on AddCampaignPayload {
                campaignEdge
                viewer
            }
        `;
    }
    getConfigs() {
        return [{
            type: 'RANGE_ADD',
            parentName: 'viewer',
            parentID: this.props.viewer.id,
            connectionName: 'campaigns',
            edgeName: 'campaignEdge',
            rangeBehaviors: {
              '': 'append',
            },
        }];
    }
    static fragments = {
        viewer: () => Relay.QL`
            fragment on User {
                id
            }
        `,
    };
}
```

However, since none of the components are currently querying for the range specified in RANGE_ADD (`viewer { campaigns }`), Relay intelligently excludes that query from the `AddCampaignPayload`.

This results in a console warning:

```
Warning: writeRelayUpdatePayload(): Expected response payload to include the newly created edge `campaignEdge` and its `node` field. Did you forget to update the `RANGE_ADD` mutation config?
```

I really want to get back the ID of the newly created model, so that I can navigate the client to it.  For example, getting back the new `campaignEdge`, I want to send the client to `/campaigns/${campaignEdge.node.id}`.

Is there any way to tell Relay to fetch that edge?  Have I configured this mutation correctly?

Comment: Why not just return it in the payload?

Comment: @ChrisMartin Relay controls the payload.  I needed to figure out how to control Relay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `REQUIRED_CHILDREN` in this context. For more details, see https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/237 and https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/236.

`REQUIRED_CHILDREN` lets you specify an extra data dependency for exactly this pattern.